# Take a temporarily control of the system using Java

Tags: java, operating-system

I have developed an app for showing some information to the employees of a company. One of the specification was that this information must be seen at least 1 time by the employee once a while. For this purpose, I want to take the maximum control of the system for a while (10 seconds) for being sure the person sees the information. Ej: turn off the keywords and other stuff. This is my first question: Is there any classes in Java which let me do this sorts of things? In the case there isn't, is there another way, how would yo do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't at all do anything like that in java. Consider C/C++ or JNI.

Comment: That doesn't sound user friendly at all! D:

Comment: Let me guess - one of those *** disclaimers found in large companies :-) So you need a modal dialog not allowing the user to leave the application before clicking 'I agree' or waiting for a certain time?

Comment: @home thanks a dialog is a great idea!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use native code for this.  Either just develop the application in some native language such as C or C++ or create a JNI DLL in C/C++ and call it from java (which is rather pointless).

Answer (score 0):

You can run your app in full screen. Thus overlay all other apps.